# iOS CGAffineTransform on UIView

Tags: ios, transform, cgaffinetransform

```
// view controller implementation
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *v;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     //self.v.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
     CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4);
     self.v.layer.affineTransform = transform;
}

@end
```

I've successfully connected `UIView *v` to a `UIView` object in the interface builder. But for some reason, when `self.v.layer.affineTransform = transform;` is executed, the `v` disappears from the screen when I build and run it. What is wrong with this? and how do I fix this? On a side note, I set the object's background color blue so it's visible on screen.

Comment: Have you check your view position before applying transform, transform code is fine, seems like your view is not present in the frame.

Comment: My view is in the middle of the screen before transform is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.v.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI_4);`

Try this.

Comment: That's really everything on my project. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Would you mind trying this out? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rprumo5f74jux5l/AADQX2f4cMzZwmNqYHa8VSGga This is what I copied from your test file, but it doesn't work on mine. Can you spot the error? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, your test file works for me as I ran it. It's just that it didn't work when I copied it to another project.